# Azure Event Hubs multiple consumers within one application

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

## Context

I have an [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) application deployed in Azure that needs to process events from an [Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/).
Within this application I want **some** events to be processed for **multiple independent features**.

## Requirements

What I want to avoid is that if one feature fails, that all other features would fail too.
Additionally, I'd like to have an easy way of retrying an event for a specific feature.

## Research

After reading the documentation and browsing the internet I've come across [Consumer Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups), which indicate that they can be used for independent parallel processing.

However, I get the feeling that Consumer Groups aren't meant for my case and should be seen more as 1 consumer group **per application** rather than 1 consumer group **per feature**.
**Am I correct in this assumption?**

After searching more, I haven't really come across anyone tackling this problem, while it feels to me as if it should be quite common.
**How would this normally be achieved?**

## Potential solution?

One thing I have been considering is to have a single Azure Function that receives all events.
When an event is received, this Azure Function would check who is interested in the event and would then per feature send the same event to a different Event Hub with an indication of which feature it should be processed for (partitioned by the feature).
This would then allow the events to be processed independently per feature.

**Is this a "normal" way of processing events via Event Hub?**
**Are there any pitfalls that I'm missing?**

Comment: *Additionally, I'd like to have an easy way of retrying an event for a specific feature.* You mean in case of a failure?

Comment: Question: have you considered using Event Grid instead? So features can subscribe to events they want to handle.

Comment: @PeterBons yes, I'm mainly thinking of failures. In general I'm trying to build a system that is serviceable, so in case an event has failed in the past and has been lost, it ***would be nice*** to be able to re-send the event for a specific feature.

Comment: @PeterBons I have considered Event Grid. What scares me away from Event Grid is the overhead of managing topic/subscriptions for individual features (40+ subscriptions). What draws me to Event Hubs is the message retention and partitioning. But maybe I'm weighing these incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your scenario correctly, it sounds like you have multiple independent features, each of which would like a unique view of events flowing through the system.  Each feature should process independently and be isolated from other features to prevent cascading failures.   Assuming that's correct, I'd first start with a question:

Are you seeing events flow through at a high enough scale that Event Hubs makes sense?  To me, it seems like a Service Bus topic with a subscription for each feature may be the more natural pattern.  Unless you're processing a high volume of events consistently, it may be worth exploring.

If you're convinced that Event Hubs is the right fit, then I'd consider the following skeleton to start exploring from, assuming that you're also sticking with Functions:

- One consumer group per feature.  *(note: There's a limit of 20 consumer groups for a standard instance; if you have more than 20 features, you would need to either consider sharding among multiple Event Hub instances or using a dedicated tier)*
- One Function per feature, bound to the associated consumer group

The consumer groups will allow you to have the isolation that you're looking for, with features being independent and being able to recover/reprocess without impacting other features.  It will also allow you to scale horizontally much more efficiently with Functions managing.

I wouldn't advise using a single function for all instances.  You'll end up having a lot more complexity that you have to manage directly in order to track the state of each feature independently, as checkpoints and state for reading the partition exist at the consumer group level.  You would also be doing considerably more work in a single instance, making it more difficult to scale effectively.  The best you'd be able to do would be one instance for each partition of the Event Hub.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why a "Service Bus topic with subscription for each feature" feels more "natural"? While I agree that in terms of running cost, this would probably be more cost effective. To me it feels like a lot of overhead to create a new subscription for each specific feature. Currently it would mean roughly 40 subscriptions and this list is sure to change for each release.

Comment: Service Bus allows you control over message completion, failure recovery, and poison message handling at the service-level, which Event Hubs does not.  Your application has less infrastructure work to do for managing processing state with Service Bus, at the cost of lower message throughput.  Management of subscriptions can be automated as part of your development or deployment process in a variety of ways or dynamically at runtime using the Service Bus SDK.  You'll likely have the management overhead regardless for consumer groups and/or sharding between Event Hub instances.